# PHP create session for later PHP page

Tags: php, session

I want to save some values to the $_SESSION variable, I tried to create sessions like this:

```
 if(isset($row_WADAsarenewals['AgreeNum'])) {    
        $_SESSION['AgreeNum'] = $row_WADAsarenewals['AgreeNum'];
 }
```

But when I try to display this session like this it does not show up? `echo($AgreeNum);`  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you read the [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) part of the PHP manual.

Comment: Look at what Thomas wrote below - whenever you access SESSION data, you have to start the session at THE VERY BEGINNING of the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To echo your session you will need to call the session-variable, not a regular variable with the same name as the the session-variable. So your echo would be:

```
echo $_SESSION["AgreeNum"];
```

Also, if you are having problems writing to your session, you might have to call [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) prior to writing anything to your session.

Comment: I ended up using $_SESSION['AgreeNum'] = $_GET['AgreeNum']; and then calling the session as you described.  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
session_start()
```

at the beginning of your new script.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `session_start();` prior to store something on the `$_SESSION`.

Then on the page you want to display the stored values, resume the session by calling again the `session_start();` function. And retrieve the stored data like `$AgreeNum = $_SESSION['AgreeNum'];`

A call to `echo($AgreeNum);` should output the stored value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do;

```
echo $_SESSION['AgreeNum'];
```

Your solution just work when you have http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php turned on, which is not recommended. Because then $AgreeNum can came from $_GET for example.